# Is missing or adding a word accidentally in a citation serious mistake. Can it be fixed before publishing?

Tags: citations, peer-review

You accidentally made a mistake in a citation in a submitted paper. For example, you cited a list from one author and you accidently made a mistake in one of the bullets. Let's say you added a word you shouldn't have or you missed a word. Is it ok to make those changes after the peer review stage? It feels bad to make such a mistake when citing a list, but hopefully it can be fixed later.

What do you think about it? In general, are these mistakes that uncommon and is it ok to fix them later?

How common is it that there are some mistakes even in published materials? Are they a reason for serious problems?

Comment: first of all, this means reviewers did not verify the citations, at the very least, not manually, and not with a citation verifier software, either

Comment: @ivan866 Of course not, that's way below their "pay" grade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** At the revision stage you can certainly still fix additional small mistakes. Just make sure to include a statement in your rebuttal letter explaining the additional changes you made.

However I would be careful with larger changes like adding an additional analysis as reviewers might feel that you are trying to sneak something past them.

Comment: Thank you! Are these mistakes uncommon or common? I have read discussion where people mentined noticing these mistakes even in published materials? It feels awful to accidently miss a word in citation. For example, instead of "percieved price" to put just "price". I know it's a mistake, but don't know how serious and common. However, it's good it can be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @Academicaeconomica Happens sometimes - nobody is perfect ;) Even in published material but then it is more complicated and you need to submit a "corrigendium"  e.g. https://www.elsevier.com/editors/perk/policy-and-best-practice-errata-And-corrigenda (but journals don't like that very much)

Comment: Are these mistakes considered plagiarism or just mistakes that should be fiexed?